# Visualforce Page Column Sizing

Tags: visualforce, pageblocktable

I have a VF page with a custom controller that calculates grand totals and sub totals for some of my object's numeric values.  I have these in separate pageBlockTable tags in my page.  Both sections have the same headers.  All works well, but I'm having an issue when the browser page is re-sized.  The grand total pageBlockTable (which contains headers) sizes at a different rate than the sub-total pageBlockTable.  So the columns end up being different sizes, even though they share the same width percentage.  Does anyone know a way around this?

***VF Page:***

```
<apex:page StandardController="Quote__c" recordSetVar="quotes" Extensions="CalculateQLISummary" action="{!init}" tabStyle="Quote__c">
    <apex:pageMessages id="pgMess" />

    <style type="text/css">
        .SectHeader {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size:10pt;
            background: #288fb0;
            color: white;
            width:100%;
            border:1px solid black;
            padding:8px;
            border-radius:5px;
            }
        .TblHeader {
            display: None;
            }
        .col{
            text-align:center;
            }
        .txt{
            text-align:center;
            }
    </style>

    <apex:form id="frmReview" > 
        <apex:pageBlock id="pgBlckQSummary" title="Quote Line Summary">
            <center><apex:commandButton title="Back to Quote" value="Back to Quote" action="{!cancel}"/></center><br/><br/>

        <apex:outputText value="AGGREGATE AMOUNTS" styleClass="SectHeader"/><p/>

            <apex:pageBlockTable title="GRAND TOTAL" value="{!GT}" var="gt" style="width:100%">

                <apex:column headerValue="Contract Year" styleClass="txt" headerClass="col" style="width:33.33%">
                    <apex:outputText value="TOTAL CONTRACT"/>
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="List Price" styleClass="txt" headerClass="col" style="width:33.33%">
                    {!gt['TotLP2']}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Final Price" styleClass="txt" headerClass="col" style="width:33.33%">
                    {!gt['TotFP2']}
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockTable title="Summary" value="{!YT}" var="quoteTot" style="width:100%">

                <apex:column headerValue="Contract Year" styleClass="txt" headerClass="TblHeader" style="width:33.33%">
                    {!quoteTot['YrCY']}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="List Price" styleClass="txt" headerClass="TblHeader" style="width:33.33%">
                    {!quoteTot['YrLP2']}
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Final Price" styleClass="txt" headerClass="TblHeader" style="width:33.33%">
                    {!quoteTot['YrFP2']}
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering, I figured this out for my use case.  I increased the header percentage for the columns that had the largest header and decreased others to make them add to 100%. So I ended up with a 40% - 30% - 30% split and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You should specify the "correct" size to have the best chance of your columns being sized correctly: 33%, or perhaps even 33.33% for better accuracy. Using 20% for each column means the browser is open to determine where the remaining 40% of the table goes to.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but I am still getting the same issue.  The section that has the headers shrinks at a lower rate than the one without the headers.